# AWS Cognito - social sign-in option behaviour

Tags: android, ios, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We have implemented social sign-up, and login, options for our consumer facing app *(iOS, Android and React Native web app)* and we are using AWS Cognito and FB OAuth to handle the authentication of users.

We are not yet live but have found an 'issue' with the way a user is authenticated via this method. I only have a basic level of tech knowledge in this area so please forgive any dummies language I use.

Essentially the requirement is for our app to only prompt a user for their Facebook credentials *(for sign-up or login)* **IF** and **ONLY IF** they **do not have** an active and logged in Facebook session on that browser.

e.g.

- If user is logged into FB on that browser and wants to login to our app, our app is able to 'see' that there is an active FB login, utilise that to authenticate the user and log them into our app.
- If a user **is not** logged into FB on that browser and wants to login to our app, our app is able to 'see' that there **is not** an active FB login and thus prompt the user to provide their FB credentials in order to authenticate themself. Assuming they do this successfully, they are then logged into our app.

If a user logs out of our app and then returns later and wants to login again, the above 'test' is run to check whether we can authenticate them immediately, or whether they need to be prompted to provide FB credentials.

Our current understanding from our tech partner is that this is not possible, but keen to understand if anyone has managed to do it using the technologies we are using?

Lastly, has anyone successfully utilised the FB SDKs for iOS and Android alongside AWS Cognito to allow their app to use the native FB app *(on device)* as a route to authentication *(vs. pushing them to a web page where the user has to enter FB creds)*?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

As part of OAuth 2.0 (you didn't specify), the flow would be routed through a browser. The identity provider would have access to the cookies stored in the browser and should be able to pickup on any active sessions. This you should not need to worry about unless you implemented your own cookie store or browser.

The FB SDKs give options for login behavior ranging from reading the session from the Facebook app to browser. These are documented for [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/facebook/com/facebook/login/loginbehavior.html/) and [iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/).

Comment: How to integrate fb login with aws-amplify (cognito)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @donkon already pointed out, your native app will not have access to any credentials stored in the user agent (browser) where the authorization has been performed. This is intended behaviour and increases security.

When your client requires to get client credentials (aka access token) for *your* app and has to authenticate the user via an external IdP (here FB) you typically run this authentication process in a user agent. The behaviour of this site depends on the IdP and can be somewhat tailored with options provided as query parameters in the URL which calls out to the IdP. Note that FB Login is neither fully OAuth2 nor OIDC conformant.

For Facebook Login, the relevant parameter to tailor the flow is `auth_type` which is akin to the `prompt` option for an OIDC conformant IdP. It's valid values are of course vendor specific as well:  `reauthenticate`, `https`, `rerequest`.

Still, the questions remains, how you can possibly customise the AWS Cognito sign-up and sign-in flow which may forward parameters to the FB Login IdP. I cannot answer this myself, since I have not used AWS Cognito so far.

But as far as I can see, your requirements cannot be 100% fulfilled, since your app cannot "see" that there is a valid session in the user agent. What's important though is, whether the behaviour is acceptable from a UX point of view - and of course most important, it must be secure.

**Reference:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking/